# Выравнивание div-ов. Получение длины div-а

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, выравнивание, width

Есть `div`-ы

```css
#choosedatetimebegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

.labeldatetimebegin {
    width:  305px;
}

.datetimeinput {
    width: 100%-305px;
}

#chooseduration {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.duration {
    width: 424px;
}

.durationinput {
    width: 100%-424px;
}
```

```html
<div id="choosedatetimebegin">
  <div class="labeldatetimebegin">Дата/время</div>
  <div class="datetimeinput"><input type="datetime-local" id="datetimebegin" name="datetimebegin" step=1></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="chooseduration">
  <div class="duration">Продолжительность</div>
  <div class="durationinput"><input type="time" step='1' min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59" id="durationtime"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Каким образом можно получить длину `div`-ов в `html`и `php` (в `js` как я понимаю у элемента есть свойство `width`), чтобы не вручную подгонять по размеру элементы, а с учетом вычисленной длины `labeldatetimebegin`, `duration`?
2. Вообще каким образом можно получить длину `div`-а (где угодно), чтобы в дальнейшем ее можно использовать для выравнивания (приведите пример)?

Comment: чтоб выравнивать вам не нужно знать ширину, можно использовать grid, max-content, min-content, minmax, max(), min() (CSS) зачем вам ширину знать для выравнивания, если это задача верстки?

Comment: Строго говоря, у вас не label, а div используются, но это не главное. Вы правильно понимаете, что в js можно вычислить ширину элементов. Второй div у вас шире, ну и и напишите `document.querySelector('.labeldatetimebegin').width(document.querySelector('.duration).width());`

Comment: @Greg-- можете подробнее привести примеры (в ответе) - как сверстать правильно, чтобы соблюсти размеры label-ы, а то я не понимаю как это можно сделать.

Comment: Чтоб производить вычисления в css используйте calc() 100%- 305px, так не работает. А для label, следует использовать тег label он для этого и создан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем понятен, зачем вычислять ширину.
Уточните что вы хотите получить, зачем вам ширина.

Пример - все инпуты одинаковой ширины:

```css
#choosedatetimebegin,
#chooseduration {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

#chooseduration {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="choosedatetimebegin">
  <div class="item labeldatetimebegin">Дата/время</div>
  <div class="item datetimeinput"><input type="datetime-local" id="datetimebegin" name="datetimebegin" step=1></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="chooseduration">
  <div class="item duration">Продолжительность</div>
  <div class="item durationinput"><input type="time" step='1' min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59" id="durationtime"></div>
</div>
```

Пример - все колонки с инпутами 30% от ширины колонки:

```css
#choosedatetimebegin,
#chooseduration {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 30%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

#chooseduration {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="choosedatetimebegin">
  <div class="item labeldatetimebegin">Дата/время</div>
  <div class="item datetimeinput"><input type="datetime-local" id="datetimebegin" name="datetimebegin" step=1></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="chooseduration">
  <div class="item duration">Продолжительность</div>
  <div class="item durationinput"><input type="time" step='1' min="00:00:00" max="23:59:59" id="durationtime"></div>
</div>
```

Список литературы:
[тег label](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)
[Вычисления в CSS, функция calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc())
[Верстка grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
Так же пригодится величины [max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max()), [min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()), [minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/minmax()), [max-content и min-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/minmax())